# How to use Mapper.Map with ConstructUsing and AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a simple question: How to use `Mapper.Map` inside `ConstructUsing`? I'm using AutoMapper v4.1.1 and I have this piece of code that I want to cleanup by reusing the code.

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<SKU, SKUViewModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(m => new SKUViewModel(
    (from texts in m.DescriptionTranslation.TranslationTexts
        select new TranslationTuple
        {
            LanguageId = texts.LanguageId,
            LanguageDisplayName = texts.Language.DisplayName,
            TranslationText = texts.Text,
            NeutralText = texts.NeutralText,
            ThreeLetterIsoLanguageName = texts.Language.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
        }).ToList(),
        (from texts in m.DisplayNameTranslation.TranslationTexts
        select new TranslationTuple
        {
             LanguageId = texts.LanguageId,
             LanguageDisplayName = texts.Language.DisplayName,
             TranslationText = texts.Text,
             NeutralText = texts.NeutralText,
             ThreeLetterIsoLanguageName = texts.Language.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
        }).ToList(),
        (from texts in m.PaypalDescriptionTranslation.TranslationTexts
        select new TranslationTuple
        {
             LanguageId = texts.LanguageId,
             LanguageDisplayName = texts.Language.DisplayName,
             TranslationText = texts.Text,
             NeutralText = texts.NeutralText,
             ThreeLetterIsoLanguageName = texts.Language.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
        }).ToList()));
```

I know we can use `Mapper.Map` with the `AfterMap` method like this `.AfterMap((s, d) => Mapper.Map(s.CompanyProfile, d));`

But I'm not able to do the same inside `ConstructUsing`.

Any suggestion ?

David

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have mappings defined for these entities, you could call Mapper.Map on it. For sample:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<SKU, SKUViewModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(m => 
    {
        var descriptions = Mapper.Map<List<TranslationTuple>>(m.DescriptionTranslation.TranslationTexts);
        var displays = Mapper.Map<List<TranslationTuple>>(m.DisplayNameTranslation.TranslationTexts);
        var paypals = Mapper.Map<List<TranslationTuple>>(m.PaypalDescriptionTranslation.TranslationTexts);
        
        return new SKUViewModel(descriptions, displays, paypals);
    });
```

Then, when you need to create an object mapped by automapper, just use:

```cs
var viewModel = Mapper.Map<List<SKUViewModel>>(sku);
```

Methods like `ConstructUsing`, `AfterMap`, `BeforeMap` are methods that is executed after you have everything defined. So, following this logic, it should execute `Mapper.Map<>` without problems.

Comment: From version 4.2 of Automapper it's deprecated to use static method Mapper.Map(). So you should use ConstructUsing() with ResolutionContext and call ResolutionContext.Engine.Map().

Comment: @AndreyBurykin do you have an example implementation?

Comment: @Jack Here is a good article with examples: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/

Comment: example:
            CreateMap<S, D>().ConstructUsing(
                context =>
                {
                    var entity = (S)context.SourceValue;

                    return new D
                    {
                        Id = entity.Id,
                        c = context.Engine.Mapper.Map<C>entity.c)
                    };
                });

Comment: i had to go things like .ConstructUsing((s, c) => c.Mapper.Map<Order, OrderViewModel>(s.Order))